# How to create JS function that will confirm the submission of the form, when not all fields are completed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, web-deployment

I was wondering how to create a function in JS/JQuery that upon clicking submit button (if some fields are not completed) the confirmation pop-out will show up, and if users clicks NO the POST method won't work. I'am pretty stucked... XD

Comment: Have you tried `$("form").on("submit", function() { return confirm("Continue?"); });`

Comment: Yes but it works always, and I want it to work only when some fields are not filled. I tried doing it by if($('#field')==""){confirm("Continue")} but it didin't work out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you can try something like add class to all the form fields you want to make sure that are not empty and then run something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var flag = ture;
$("yourButton").click(function(){
        $(".myclass").each(function(){
       if($(this).val() == '') flag = false;
    })
if(!flag) {// do what ever}
})
})
```

something like this.
again your question is a bit "big" cos we got nothing to work with.

gl.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what you're looking for is just [jQuery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/).

You can check their [demo page](https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/) to see some example and learn how to use it.

Comment: I've seen it, but there is only option for a field to be requiered and I want to confirme that a user want to leave some fieldes blanck